# Excel-Macro to fill serial numbers to filtered data

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have 3 columns A,B & C. The data is in B & C. I filter Column C to show "Unique records only". Now I want to add serial numbers to this filtered data in Column A. Be advised that the number of rows in the list (and therefore the filtered list) is not fixed. 
I know the function (=SUBTOTAL(3,$B$1:B2)-1 ) but this requires manual intervention. I also [found](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/670850-auto-fill-serial-number-macro.html) the VBA code that works on an unfiltered list:

```
Sub FillSerialNumbers()
  With Range("A3:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = 1
    .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1, Trend:=False
  End With
End Sub
```

However I'm unable to implement it on a filtered list. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way

```
  Set rRng = Range("A3:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
  Dim cntr As Integer: cntr = 1

  For Each cell In rRng
    If cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value = cntr
        cntr = cntr + 1
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: I keep getting this error:
`Run time error 1004  
Data series method of Range-class failed` 
This works fine on unfiltered list though.

Comment: Won't this print all 1s?? It's not getting incremented.

Comment: Yes, I was focused on the loop.  I added in the counter.

Answer (score 0):

As a formula solution, you could try, in cell A3 and copied down:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(C$3:C3,C3)=1,C3<>""),max(A$2:A2)+1,"")
```

Comment: The whole thing needs to run without manual intervention. As such formulas, though easier, are out of the question.